# JQuery Creating tabs, issues with tabs() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to understand the code snippet to create tabs dynamically in my asp.net web application. I am a novice in JQuery, I understood that "tabsDiv.tabs("add", '#main', pages[i][0]);" is deprecated and I am trying to figure out way to get my tabs working with the new way of implementing it. I could not understand the below part of the code,

```
tabsDiv.tabs({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

full code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var pages = [
            ['Events', "/ListEvents.aspx", "/AddEvent.aspx", "UpdateOrDeleteEvent.aspx"],
            ['Performance', "/Performance.aspx"]
        ];

        var myPage = '<%=Request.Path %>';

        var tabsDiv = $('#masterTabsDiv');

        tabsDiv.tabs({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
                return false;
            }
        });

        var indexToSelect = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < pages[i].length; j++) {
                if (pages[i][j] == myPage) {
                    indexToSelect = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            tabsDiv.tabs("add", '#main', pages[i][0]);
        }

        tabsDiv.find('li').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');
        tabsDiv.find('li').eq(indexToSelect).addClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but this is about s different aspect of the same question, I wanted to know about a particular method inside it so started a new thread..

Comment: If you want to dynamically add tabs, you can : 1) add a tab (<li>) in the <ul> element, 2) add another tab content (<div>) after the <ul> element, 3) then call `tabsDiv.tabs('refresh');`

Comment: yes, I got it. But my question is what "tabsDiv.tabs({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
                    return false;
                }
            }); " doing in my code (I got this snippet from a forum so I am just trying to understand that function there.. ), when I ran this code in Chrome dev. tools it seems I cannot set a break point to see what it coming up with as the function is skipped altogether..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this code doing?

```
document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
```

It's changing the location to something like `#tab1` so that the tab header will be selected and show the content of that tab. It's simply forcing an event so that the framework knows a user `clicked` on a tab.